# WsdlUI posting to complex types

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl

I have downloaded [WsdlUI](https://github.com/drexyia/WsdlUI), a open source C# SOAP client that is able to consume and process WCF messages without needing to add a reference. I can post to a method that has simple types(like strings and ints). When the WCF method has a complex type the XML envelope is incorrect. I am somewhat a noob to WCF and am a little lost with all the code... someone please help; how do I get the XML to return the correct XML?

I enabled tracing on my server and here is the valid xml envelope from a console app that has the service reference added:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
    <To s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://host.com/BG.WCF/Service.svc</To>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/MobileInterface/CreateQueuedMsg</Action>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
<CreateQueuedMsg xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <Token>add568d9-45e0-0000-98a5-762b84989797</Token>
    <BGSMSMessage xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BG.Bus.Mobile.Classes" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:BusinessID>Test</a:BusinessID>
        <a:CommsGUID>eca403e7-1116-4bc3-a476-31e91c4ca33f</a:CommsGUID>
        <a:DestinationAddress>+27000000000</a:DestinationAddress>
        <a:Msg>test msg</a:Msg>
        <a:MsgEncodingType>Default</a:MsgEncodingType>
        <a:SendDT>2014-02-24T07:21:45.3187492+02:00</a:SendDT>
        <a:SystemID>Test</a:SystemID>
        <a:ValidityDT>2014-02-27T07:21:45.3187492+02:00</a:ValidityDT>
    </BGSMSMessage>
    <smsRoute xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BG.Bus.Mobile.Classes" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:SMSRoute>BGWASP</a:SMSRoute>
    </smsRoute>
</CreateQueuedMsg>
</s:Body>
```

here is the envelope WsdlUi returns:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <To s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://bgvm08mbl01.businessgenetics.co.za/BG.Bus/BG.Bus.Mobile.WCF/MobileService.svc</To>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/MobileInterface/CreateQueuedMsg</Action>
</s:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <CreateQueuedMsg xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <Token>ADD568D9-45E0-498E-98A5-762B84989797</Token>
        <BGSMSMessage>
            <BusinessID>Test</BusinessID>
            <CommsGUID>559eb322-7b01-438d-93f1-74b1aafccc4f</CommsGUID>
            <DestinationAddress>0000000000</DestinationAddress>
            <Msg>Testers2014-02-24 07:37:53</Msg>
            <MsgEncodingType>Default</MsgEncodingType>
            <SendDT>2014-02-24 07:37:53</SendDT>
            <SystemID>Test</SystemID>
            <ValidityDT>2014-02-27 07:37:53</ValidityDT>
        </BGSMSMessage>
        <smsRoute>
            <SMSRoute>BGWASP</SMSRoute>
            <SMSRoute>GV</SMSRoute>
        </smsRoute>
    </CreateQueuedMsg>
</soap:Body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am the developer of WsdlUI so thanks for using it.

The application currently does not work with complex types due to the bug that you are referring to.

I should have a release out mid June that will fix this problem.

Thanks for the detailed description of the problem in your post.

Comment: I have created a work around for the time being but I look forward to your next release. Thank you.

Comment: Can you email me at the address in my profile. I will send you an updated version of WsdlUI that should include a fix for this. I want to check that the next version fixes this bug before release.